# Automatic scaling based on custom metrics

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Does AppEngine Flexible Environment support automatic scaling based on custom metrics? As per [introduction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#instance_scaling), they do auto scaling based on resource utilization and other application metrics but did not find any thing related to application metrics in [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling).

Answer (score 0):

That isn't supported in App Engine Flexible yet, but it's on the roadmap. It would be certainly helpful if you could share more about your use case (what metric would you like to use, why CPU utilization doesn't work for you) to help us prioritize the feature.

Comment: I am needing this feature based on RabbitMQ queue size.